# How to get total size of a folder in C with recursivity?

Tags: c, recursion, directory, size, stat

All the folders have the size 4096 B.

How do I get the total size of a folder with all the file size inside?

For example:

```
> Dir1 (4096)
> -- File1.txt (100)
> -- Dir 2 (4096)
> ---- File2.txt (100)
```

When I try to get the size of Dir1, it gives me 4096.
The expected answer I wish to get is 8392

Another example:

```
DirA (4096)
-- FileA (100)
-- FileB (100)
```

The total should be 4296

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm but I can't find a way to detect if it's a folder or not. Sorry for the "vulgar" code below...

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *dp;
struct stat fileStat;
    int getTotalDirSize()
    {
        while()
        {
            if(/*Detect Folder/Directory*/)
            {
            totalSize += 4096;
                getTotalDirSize();
            }
            else
            {
                totalSize += fileSize;
            }

        }

        return totalSize;
    }
```

Note: I'm using the struct stat to get the size and the file/folder name.

Comment: Unrelated: Dunno if its even a real word, but I'm adding it to my vernacular and spamming it every chance I get at work tomorrow regardless.

Comment: On a related note, one of the attributes of a `stat` is the `st_mode` member, and if your wrap it with `S_ISDIR()` and it answers true, its a directory. Careful for `.` and `..` folders as well as symlinks. And don't forget `dirent()` can (and usually does) blast over its name buffer with each advance, so if you need to use the filenames later, make copies. For everything that is a file, just keep summing up sizes.

Comment: I'd suggest that you reuse code of du(1) from GNU coreutils instead of brewing your own. Or take a look at a similar utility from BSD userland.

Comment: yes .. du(1) is a good way to find out the size of any folder specific like try as du -h --max-depth=0  /home/

Answer (score 5):

Its working using with stat but only you have to do is *give complete path to the stat* like in your example Dir1->4096B then if you want to know size of the `File1.txt` use in stat like this:

```
strcpy(str,Dir1);   //str is a string
strcat(str,"/");
strcat(str,filename);
```

Then use `str` in stat to get size of that file. I think here you have to use *dirent structure* and DIR for folder and its contents.

For finding folder use `d_type = 4` for *dirent structure* pointer. For recursive action put all in one separate function and call it recursively until folder search completes.

```
struct stat buf;
DIR *dptr;
struct dirent *sdir;
int size=0;
char str[100];

dptr=opendir(folder);
while(sdir=readdir(dptr))
{
    if(sdir->d_type==4)
    {
        if(sdir->d_name[0]!='.')
        {
            stat(sdir->d_name,&buf);
            size=buf.st_size;
            pf("size=%d\n",size);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(str,folder);
        strcat(str,"/");
        strcat(str,sdir->d_name);
        stat(str,&buf);
        size+=buf.st_size;
        pf("size=%d\n",size);
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I use my function recursively if my function has this form:
void goNextDir(char *path[]){...} ?

With goNextDir(str); It gives error.

Comment: Take a function with two arguments. One is folder/file name and other one is path.

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching for a solution to this same problem when I encountered this thread and some others here on SO dealing with equal or similar problems (I found at the end 3 different codes aimed to calculate the total size of a folder with pure C). Unfortunately none of them worked by themselves or were incomplete, so I had to improve them (merging one into the other) and I came to the following complete and working code-and-example (should be put inside a `main.c` file, the exact folder changed and then just run). I hope it helps!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int readFolderSize(int* totalSize, char* folder)
{
    char fullPath[256];
    struct dirent *dirData;
    struct stat buffer;
    int exists;
    DIR *poDir;
    int resp = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    poDir = opendir(folder);

    if (poDir == NULL)
    {
        perror("general_getFolderSize: poDir fail!");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((dirData = readdir(poDir)))
    {
        if (dirData == NULL)
        {
            const unsigned int err = errno;

            fprintf(stderr, "general_getFolderSize: Failed in readdir (%u)\n",err);

            resp = EXIT_FAILURE;

            continue;
        }

        //
        if (dirData->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            if (dirData->d_name[0] != '.')
            {
                //printf("general_getFolderSize: Is a directory: %s\n", dirData->d_name);

                strcpy(fullPath,folder);
                strcat(fullPath,"/");
                strcat(fullPath,dirData->d_name);

                //printf("general_getFolderSize: Accessing dir: %s\n", fullPath);

                if (readFolderSize(totalSize,fullPath) == EXIT_FAILURE)
                    resp = EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(fullPath,folder);
            strcat(fullPath,"/");
            strcat(fullPath,dirData->d_name);

            exists = stat(fullPath,&buffer);

            if (exists < 0)
            {
                const unsigned int err = errno;

                fprintf(stderr, "general_getFolderSize: Failed in stat (file) %s: %u\n", fullPath,err);

                resp = EXIT_FAILURE;

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                (*totalSize) += buffer.st_size;

                //printf("general_getFolderSize: Item size (file) (%s): %d\n",fullPath,(int)buffer.st_size);
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(poDir);

    return resp;
}

/*!
 * \brief general_getFolderSize returns the size of a folder in bytes.
 * \param folder is the name of the folder (preferentially without a '/' at the end)
 * \param totalSize is a pointer where the result value is given
 * \return
 */
int general_getFolderSize(char* folder, int* totalSize)
{
    printf("general_getFolderSize: Start\n");

    //
    if (readFolderSize(totalSize,folder) == EXIT_FAILURE)
    {
        perror("general_getFolderSize: Call to readFolderSize failed!");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //
    printf("general_getFolderSize: Stop\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    int folderSize;

    if (general_getFolderSize("/home/maiquel/Documents/TEMP/maindir",&folderSize) == EXIT_FAILURE)
    {
        printf("Error reading folder size!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Folder size: %d b (%d kb / %d Mb)\n", folderSize, folderSize/1024, folderSize/(1024 * 1024));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

P.s.: Although I'm aware that `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are not supposed to be used as function return values, I preferred to do so instead of creating new defines in the name of code simplicity.